# Piping data to Gnuplot from C

Tags: c, plot, pipe, gnuplot

I've managed to create some code which will continuously send data points from a C program to gnuplot to show evolution of a time dependent Schrodinger equation. This is the function I've made which is iterated in a loop which updates the `WF[]` values each time:
(Both `x[]` and `WF[]` are 1d)

```
void gnuprint(FILE *gp, double x[], int N)
{     
    int i;
    fprintf(gp, "plot '-' with lines\n");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){fprintf(gp, "%g %g\n", x[i],WF[2*i+1]);}
    fflush(gp);
    fprintf(gp, "e\n");  
}
```

What I really want to do next is plot the imaginary points on the same plot which are next to the real in the array:  `x[i]`, `WF[2*i+2]`

If I simply just add a

```
fprintf(gp, "%g %g\n", x[i],WF[2*i+2]); //The imaginary values
```

into the loop, when 'with lines' specified, the two plots link together (plot points join up). Using dots solves this but I would like both plots to be separately linked with lines and hopefully different colours. Can someone help?

This is the form of the plot i'd like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data which is piped to gnuplot can be used only once. So, if you want to have two plots, with different colors, you must use `'-'` twice and then send your data sets one after the other, separated by an `e`:

```
void gnuprint(FILE *gp, double x[], int N)
{     
    int i;
    fprintf(gp, "plot '-' with lines, '-' with lines\n");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){fprintf(gp, "%g %g\n", x[i],WF[2*i+1]);}
    fflush(gp);
    fprintf(gp, "e\n");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){fprintf(gp, "%g %g\n", x[i],WF[2*i+2]);}
    fflush(gp);
    fprintf(gp, "e\n");  
}
```

Comment: Do you also know if I can plot to the same gnuplot window after each command instead of it closing and opening a new window each time?

Comment: That depends on your overall program structure. If you only call your `gnuprint` function, it should always plot to the same window.

Comment: One more thing, if you can help, is there a clean way to quit my loop before its finished iterating? At the moment I just close the command prompt and then it stops working and windows doesn't like it.