# Use of FILE* in C to open command tools and feed data

Tags: c, file, gnuplot

I've been researching ways of visualizing data and stumbled upon gnuplot. It seems great and really useful but I was trying to find a way of embedding it within the program itself instead of having to feel the data separately. I then stumbled on a stack overflow answer where the topic was discussed but they gloss over how certain things work since it didn't pertain to their question at the moment so I'm asking here:

Their post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730732/piping-data-to-gnuplot-from-c):

So the code extract would be:

```
void gnuprint(FILE *gp, double x[], int N){     
     int i;
     fprintf(gp, "plot '-' with lines\n");

     for (i=0; i<N; i++){fprintf(gp, "%g %g\n", x[i],WF[2*i+1]);}
     fflush(gp);
     fprintf(gp, "e\n");                                                                
}
```

From what I understand from the code they seem to have opened the gnuplot program as a file and piping in the information as if it was writing into a file. I simply fail to understand how one would initialize the gp pointer to hold the program open in such a state. Any help understanding how this is done would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where do you read that they opened gnuplot as a file? Piping data into gnuplot could be simply as `./myprog | gnuplot` where you just write to `stdout` and `gnuplot` will read it from `stdin`. Unfortunately your linked question does not reveal more details.

Comment: Maybe [`popen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html)?

Comment: @Gerhardh I understood they had opened gnuplot as a file since they seem to be writing to a FILE* calle gp. There isn't any further code so I just have to assume there's a way of interfacing with command tools using FILE type? 

I've been researching more and there seems to be a gnuplot-iostream library. Maybe they didn't interface with gnuplot the way I originally thought and instead through the iostream lib. Still looking further

Comment: @Gerhardh I haven't been able to get gnuplot to plot via piping as you showed. ./myprog | gnuplot starts to as for a script name for it to run it itself and that isn't what my goal would be

Comment: Just remember `popen()` is like a more contained (and more limited) way of doing shell redirection. At its heart it is shell redirection.

Comment: I'm afraid that you are misled by the name. `gp` looks like the file that contains the commands for gnuplot. Choosing names is a difficult thing.

Comment: @thebusybee
Yeah, I've been going down the rabbit whole and finding out about cpp interacting with the shell. Originally I did understand that gp is the file containing the command but before then I had no idea something like that was possible. I've been able to get the command to open up with a test program but I'm still having issues understanding how I would get gnuplot to receive the commands once it has been initialized by popen().

I would love for popen() to work both ways so I can try and see what issues I'm stumbling into but there are the limitations pmg brought up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code extract you give for gnuprint() is incomplete or a bit mangled. It provides no definition for WF[].   Removing that and wrapping it in a minimal main.c gives the following simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gnuprint(FILE *, double *, int);

int main()
{
    double x[7] = {11,55,22,44,33,77,66};
    FILE *gp;

    /* Open a pipe to gnuplot giving the 'persist' option */
    gp = popen("gnuplot -p", "w");
    gnuprint(gp, x, 7);
}

void gnuprint(FILE *gp, double x[], int N)
{     
     int i;
     fprintf(gp, "plot '-' with lines\n");

     for (i=0; i<N; i++){fprintf(gp, "%d %g\n", i, x[i]);}
     fflush(gp);
     fprintf(gp, "e\n");                                                                
}
```

This compiles, links, and builds to give an executable that invokes "gnuplot -p" and feeds it commands and data to plot.  The "-p" option to gnuplot tells it to leave the plot showing on the screen after it exits.

Comment: Honestly, you're pretty awesome for helping out in the way you did.